# Why ACTION_UP works different for Button and TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-button

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>

View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    String view = "";

    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.button:
        view = "button";
        break;

      case R.id.text_view:
        view = "text_view";
        break;
    }

    Log.i(view, "event.getAction: " + event.getAction());

    return false;
  }
};

View btn = this.findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnTouchListener(listener);

btn = this.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
btn.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

**Output:**

```
button: event.getAction: 0
button: event.getAction: 1
button: event.getAction: 0
button: event.getAction: 2
button: event.getAction: 2
button: event.getAction: 2
button: event.getAction: 2
button: event.getAction: 2
button: event.getAction: 2
button: event.getAction: 2
button: event.getAction: 1
text_view: event.getAction: 0
text_view: event.getAction: 0
text_view: event.getAction: 0
text_view: event.getAction: 0
text_view: event.getAction: 0
```

**Question:** Why ACTION_UP and ACTION_MOVE events are being sent for the Button and aren't being sent for the TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Activity.**dispatchTouchEvent**() returns **true** for the ACTION_DOWN if a Button is touched and returns **false** if a TextView is touched. This difference causes the behavior mentioned in the question.